# What is the difference between R functions prcomp and princomp?

Tags: r, pca

I compared `?prcomp` and `?princomp` and found something about Q-mode and R-mode principal component analysis (PCA). But honestly – I don't understand it. Can anybody explain the difference and maybe even explain when to apply which?

Comment: Is the question oen about the difference between the functions prcomp and princomp in R or about the difference between "Q-mode" and "R-mode PCA"?  The two are unrelated.

Comment: It's been a while. But I'll check as soon as I have time. IIRC I actually had some differences...

Comment: Related: [Why do the R functions 'princomp' and 'prcomp' give different eigenvalues?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/9500)

Answer (score 59):

The difference between them is nothing to do with the type of PCA they perform, just the method they use. As [the help page](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/prcomp.html) for `prcomp` says:

> The calculation is done by a singular value decomposition of the (centered and possibly scaled) data matrix, not by using `eigen` on the covariance matrix. This is generally the preferred method for numerical accuracy.

On the other hand, the `princomp` [help page](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/princomp.html) says:

> The calculation is done using `eigen` on the correlation or covariance matrix, as determined by `cor`. This is done for compatibility with the S-PLUS result. A preferred method of calculation is to use `svd` on `x`, as is done in `prcomp`."

So, **`prcomp` is preferred**, although in practice you are unlikely to see much difference (for example, if you run the examples on the help pages you should get identical results).

Comment: There are some gruesome technical details on the different underlying linear algebra and LAPACK routines used in my answer to [Why are principal components in PCA (eigenvectors of the covariance matrix) mutually orthogonal?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/130882/why-are-principal-components-in-pca-eigenvectors-of-the-covariance-matrix-mutu)

Comment: Also, see [Why PCA of data by means of SVD of the data?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/79043) for a discussion of why SVD on the data matrix, as implemented by `prcomp`, is a preferred method.

Comment: In my experience, `prcomp` and `princomp` give slightly different estimates (for the eigen vectors particuarly) when working with data were values are very close to 0 (e.g. return calculations for financial data over short time frames), while when the data values are "large", e.g. values not extremely close to 0, the eigenvectors are almost identical to a sig. number of decimal places.

Answer (score 26):

Usually a multivariate analysis (computing correlations, extracting latents, etc.) is done of data columns which are features or questions, - while sample units, the rows, are *r*espondents. Hence this way is called **R** way analysis. Sometimes, though, you may want to do multivariate analysis of responsents, while *q*uestions are treated as sample units. That would be **Q** way analysis.

There is no formal difference between the two, so you can manage both with the same function, only transpose your data. There are differences, however, in issues of standardization and results interpretation.

This is a general reply: I don't touch specifically the R functions `prcomp` and `princomp` because I'm not an R user and am not aware of possible differences between them.

Answer (score 6):

A useful and specific [documentation from Gregory B. Anderson](http://www.ime.usp.br/%7Epavan/pdf/MAE0330-PCA-R-2013), titled **`PRINCIPAL COMPONENT ANALYSIS IN R AN EXAMINATION OF THE DIFFERENT FUNCTIONS AND METHODS TO PERFORM PCA`** has given more information on this topic. Updated [link](https://www.ime.usp.br/%7Epavan/pdf/PCA-R-2013) (7 Jan 2021).

The following two paragraph were extracted from the introduction:

> In R there are two general methods to perform PCA without any missing values: (1) spectral decomposition (R-mode [also known as eigendecomposition]) and (2) singular value decomposition (Q-mode; R Development Core Team 2011). Both of these methods can be performed longhand using the functions eigen (R-mode) and svd (Q-mode), respectively, or can be performed using the many PCA functions found in the stats package and other additional available packages. The spectral decomposition method of analysis examines the covariances and correlations between variables, whereas the singular value decomposition method looks at the covariances and correlations among the samples. While both methods can easily be performed within R, the singular value decomposition method (i.e., Q-mode) is the preferred analysis for numerical accuracy (R Development Core Team 2011).
>
> This document focuses on comparing the different methods to perform PCA in R and provides appropriate visualization techniques to examine normality within the statistical package. More specifically this document compares six different functions either created for or can be used for PCA: eigen, princomp, svd, prcomp, PCA, and pca. Throughout the document the essential R code to perform these functions is embedded within the text using the font Courier New and is color coded using the technique provided in Tinn-R (https://sourceforge.net/projects/tinn-r). Additionally, the results from the functions are compared using simulation procedure to see if the different methods differ in the eigenvalues, eigenvectors, and scores provided from the output.

Comment: Answers are better when they are standalone, because links tend to become broken (e.g. if the page moves or is deleted). Would you mind trying to expand on your answer?

Comment: @PatrickCoulombe, It has been done. Thanks for your suggestion. I will take notice of this in the future.

Answer (score 3):

They are different when both using covariance matrix. When scaling (normalizing) the training data, `prcomp` uses $n-1$ as denominator but `princomp` uses $n$ as its denominator. Difference of these two denominators is explained in [this tutorial on principal component analysis](http://www.cs.otago.ac.nz/cosc453/student_tutorials/principal_components.pdf).

Below are my test results:

```
> job<-read.table("./job_perf.txt", header=TRUE, sep="")
> pc.cr<-prcomp(job, scale=TRUE, cor=TRUE, scores=TRUE)
> pc.cr1<-princomp(job, scale=TRUE, cor=TRUE, scores=TRUE)
> pc.cr$scale
    commun probl_solv    logical      learn   physical appearance
  5.039841   1.689540   2.000000   4.655398   3.770700   4.526689
> pc.cr1$scale
    commun probl_solv    logical      learn   physical appearance
  4.805300   1.610913   1.906925   4.438747   3.595222   4.316028
```

Test data:

`commun probl_solv logical learn physical appearance
  12       52       20      44     48       16
  12       57       25      45     50       16
  12       54       21      45     50       16
  13       52       21      46     51       17
  14       54       24      46     51       17
  22       52       25      54     58       26
  22       56       26      55     58       27
  17       52       21      45     52       17
  15       53       24      45     53       18
  23       54       23      53     57       24
  25       54       23      55     58       25`