# PCA in numpy and sklearn produces different results

Tags: pca, python, scikit-learn

Am i misunderstanding something. This is my code

**using sklearn**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from sklearn import decomposition
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

pca = decomposition.PCA(n_components=3)

x = np.array([
        [0.387,4878, 5.42],
        [0.723,12104,5.25],
        [1,12756,5.52],
        [1.524,6787,3.94],
    ])
pca.fit_transform(x)
```

**Output:**

```
array([[ -4.25324997e+03,  -8.41288672e-01,  -8.37858943e-03],
   [  2.97275001e+03,  -1.25977271e-01,   1.82476780e-01],
   [  3.62475003e+03,  -1.56843494e-01,  -1.65224286e-01],
   [ -2.34425007e+03,   1.12410944e+00,  -8.87390454e-03]])
```

**Using numpy methods**

```
x_std = StandardScaler().fit_transform(x)
cov = np.cov(x_std.T)
ev , eig = np.linalg.eig(cov)
a = eig.dot(x_std.T)
```

**Output**

```
array([[ 0.06406894,  0.94063993, -1.62373172],
   [-0.35357757,  0.7509653 ,  0.63365168],
   [ 0.29312477,  0.6710958 ,  1.11766206],
   [-0.00361615, -2.36270102, -0.12758202]])
```

I have kept all 3 components but it doesnt seem to allow me to retain my original data.

May I know why is it so?

If I want to obtain back my original matrix what should I do?

Comment: Your numpy code is wrong IMHO (also, it uses `X` which is not defined). Recheck your *math*.

Comment: I am using ipython notebook so i could only copy by cells. My maths is wrong? Which part @Anony-Mousse

Comment: @Anony-Mousse Yes i realised my error but it still doesnt match up

Comment: @aceminer I am curious why you calculate covariance matrix of x_std.T, not x_std?

Comment: @EvgeniNabokov its been too long. Sry i cannot remember already

Comment: @aceminer I guess you transpose matrix because in your data "each column represents a variable, while the rows contain observations". For that case it is more informative to use the parameter rowvar = False, not transpose. See the answer from Nikolas Rieble.

Comment: Mathematically speaking, the PCA itself does not include StandardScaler().fit_transform(x); if you standardize it, the PCA is performed on the correlation matrix, rather than the co-variance matrix; that is why scikit learn does not put that step.

Comment: `x_std = StandardScaler().fit_transform(x)` is not a numpy method as per the subtitle

Comment: For others reading this question and facing the same problem. The issue could be the sign of the eigen/singular vectors computed from Scikit learn. A flip will result in different numbers but no difference in terms of performance.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The difference is because `decomposition.PCA` does not standardize your variables before doing PCA, whereas in your manual computation you call `StandardScaler` to do the standardization. Hence, you are observing this difference: [PCA on correlation or covariance?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/53)

If you replace

```
pca.fit_transform(x)
```

with

```
x_std = StandardScaler().fit_transform(x)
pca.fit_transform(x_std)
```

you will get the same result as with manual computation...

...but only up to the order of the PCs. That is because when you run

```
ev , eig = np.linalg.eig(cov)
```

you get eigenvalues not necessarily in the decreasing order. I get

```
array([ 0.07168571,  2.49382602,  1.43448827])
```

So you will want to order them manually. Sklearn does that for you.

---

Regarding reconstructing original variables, please see [How to reverse PCA and reconstruct original variables from several principal components?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/229092)

Comment: Just would like to check. Is it really necessary to standardize the matrix by its standard deviation? I seen examples where they do not do it

Comment: It is not *necessary*, it is just one way of doing it. See the link that I put in the first paragraph: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/53 -- it really is all about this question. If you standardize, you do PCA on correlations. If you do not, you do PCA on covariances.

Answer (score 20):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13224362/principal-component-analysis-pca-in-python) is a nice implementation with discussion and explanation of PCA in python. This implementation leads to the same result as the scikit PCA. This is another indicator that your PCA is wrong.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import linalg as LA

x = np.array([
        [0.387,4878, 5.42],
        [0.723,12104,5.25],
        [1,12756,5.52],
        [1.524,6787,3.94],
    ])

#centering the data
x -= np.mean(x, axis = 0)  

cov = np.cov(x, rowvar = False)

evals , evecs = LA.eigh(cov)
```

you need to sort the eigenvalues (and eigenvectors accordingly) descending

```
idx = np.argsort(evals)[::-1]
evecs = evecs[:,idx]
evals = evals[idx]

a = np.dot(x, evecs)
```

Generally, I recommend you to you check your code by implementation a simple example (as simple as possible) and calculating by hand the correct resuls (and intermediate results). This helps you to identify the problem.

Comment: Note that `linalg.eigh` assumes the input is symmetric (that is, it is optimized to read only those values from one "triangle" half of the matrix). The OP uses `linalg.eig` instead, which makes no such assumption.