# PCA principal components in sklearn not matching eigen-vectors of covariance calculated by numpy

Tags: pca, python, scikit-learn, numpy

I was trying to replicate PCA in sklearn's PCA API using numpy using [PCA in numpy and sklearn produces different results](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/235882/pca-in-numpy-and-sklearn-produces-different-results).
I noticed that:

- eigenvalues are same as the PCA object's explained_variance_ atribute along with the order
- eigenvectors are not same. Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
X = datasets.load_iris()['data']
X_scaled = StandardScaler().fit_transform(X)

pca = PCA(n_components=4)
pca.fit(X_scaled)

print('Explained Variance = ', pca.explained_variance_)
print('Principal Components = ', pca.components_)
```

This gives me:

```
Explained Variance =  [2.93808505 0.9201649  0.14774182 0.02085386]
Principal Components =  [[ 0.52106591 -0.26934744  0.5804131   0.56485654]
 [ 0.37741762  0.92329566  0.02449161  0.06694199]
 [-0.71956635  0.24438178  0.14212637  0.63427274]
 [-0.26128628  0.12350962  0.80144925 -0.52359713]]
```

Using Numpy:

```
cov = np.cov(X_scaled.T)
eig_val, eig_vec = np.linalg.eig(cov)
print('Eigenvalues = ', eig_val)
print('Eigenvectors = ', eig_vec)
```

This gives me:

```
Eigenvalues =  [2.93808505 0.9201649  0.14774182 0.02085386]
Eigenvectors =  [[ 0.52106591 -0.37741762 -0.71956635  0.26128628]
 [-0.26934744 -0.92329566  0.24438178 -0.12350962]
 [ 0.5804131  -0.02449161  0.14212637 -0.80144925]
 [ 0.56485654 -0.06694199  0.63427274  0.52359713]]
```

Notice that eigenvalues are exactly the same as `pca.explained_variance_` ie unlike the post [PCA in numpy and sklearn produces different results](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/235882/pca-in-numpy-and-sklearn-produces-different-results) suggests, we do get the eigenvalues by decreasing order in numpy (at least in this example) but eigenvectors are not same as `pca.components_`. Why is this and how do I replicate the exact result of Sklearn's PCA API manually.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

While this is a pure python related question which is not fitted here for CrossValidated, let me help you anyway. Both procedures find the correct eigenvectors. The difference is in its representation. While `PCA()` lists the entries of an eigenvectors rowwise, `np.linalg.eig()` lists the entries of the eigenvectors columnwise. Remember that eigenvectors are only unique up to a sign. Indeed, a simple check yields:

```
print(abs(eig_vec.T.round(10))==abs(pca.components_.round(10)))
[[ True,  True,  True,  True],
   [ True,  True,  True,  True],
   [ True,  True,  True,  True],
   [ True,  True,  True,  True]])
```

Comment: Thanks. I forgot that negative of eigenvectors is the same eigenvector. And I didnt know the thing about the two APIs giving row-wise vs column-wise results. This is very helpful.

Comment: Thanks for noting that negative of eigenvector is the same vector. Helped me in an assignment