# Interpreting t-SNE dimensions in terms of the original features

Tags: dimensionality-reduction, tsne

I have a dataset of 223 multilabels. I'm sure some of those labels are correlated so I want to merge them. For that I'm using sklearn tSNE to reduce the dimensions.

How can I "describe" the new dimensions in terms of the former ones, I need something like this:

```
0.5(rock) + 0.1(pop)       generated popRock    
0.2(rock) + 0.5(christian) generated christianRock
```

Answer (score 3):

This isn't possible. At a high level you can think of tSNE as pulling similar points together and pushing away dissimilar points with simulated elastic springs. There is no linear correspondence between old and new dimensions, and it's not even possible to compute a nonlinear mapping from old to new dimensions.

Comment: Thanks, even with other dimmension reduction methods?

Comment: Nevermind I found an answer https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/229092/how-to-reverse-pca-and-reconstruct-original-variables-from-several-principal-com