# Can PCA generate a new random image?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, pca, generative-models

I read [The Batch: GANs](https://blog.deeplearning.ai/blog/the-batch-gan-special-issue-ian-goodfellow-for-real-detecting-fakes-including-minorities-synthesizing-training-data-applying-virtual-make-up) newsletter and Goodfellow said:

> My colleague Bing Xu modeled face images from the Toronto Face Database, which were only 90 pixels square and grayscale. Because the faces were always centered and looking straight at the camera, **even very simple algorithms like PCA could make pretty good faces**.

I wonder how PCA can be used to make faces. As far as I know, it can be used to reconstruct image like in the article [Facial Image Compression and Reconstruction with PCA](https://shankarmsy.github.io/posts/pca-sklearn.html). But can it generate a new **random** image?

Comment: Because an image is a vector, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/229092/how-to-reverse-pca-and-reconstruct-original-variables-from-several-principal-com answers your question.  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=pca+reconstruct for more related posts.

Comment: @whuber But can it generate a new *random* image?

Comment: Sure--in a huge number of ways.  If you wish to ask that question, simply edit your post.  But please indicate what random distribution you want to use.

Comment: @whuber Not sure what random distribution means. Can it be normal distribution?

Comment: Not usually, because the components of an image are typically restricted either to the range $[0,1]$ or are limited to the integers 0, 1, ..., 255, while Normal distributions do not have that property.

Comment: @whuber Could you give an example of distribution that will work? In GANs, the input can be normal distribution.

Comment: Sure: take a linear combination of the principal components whose weights are determined by *any* distribution, followed by clamping the values of the result to the range $[0,1].$

Comment: @whuber Thanks, I just tried and it works. However, all generated images look alike.

Comment: Varying the first PCs more will cause the random images to look more different.