# Why does reversing PCA from SVD follow this formula?

Tags: pca, svd

In this [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/229093) the author writes:

> PCA is very closely related to singular value decomposition (SVD), see
> [Relationship between SVD and PCA. How to use SVD to perform PCA?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/134282) for more details. If a $n\times p$ matrix $\mathbf X$ is SVD-ed as $\mathbf X = \mathbf {USV}^\top$ and one selects a $k$-dimensional vector $\mathbf z$ that represents the point in the "reduced" $U$-space of $k$ dimensions, then to map it back to $p$ dimensions one needs to multiply it with $\mathbf S^\phantom\top_{1:k,1:k}\mathbf V^\top_{:,1:k}$.

The linked answer in the quotation says that such a reconstruction has the same dimensions $n \times p$ but lower rank. What does this term of "rank" mean in the context of PCA?

Comment: The link in the quotation provides an extensive, explicit answer.  What are you hoping we might add to it?

Comment: @whuber, sorry, I didn't read the linked answer entirely, now I see it. But I have a followup question, so I updated the original post now

Comment: PCA is linear algebra, so the default understanding of the rank of a matrix is the dimension of its image.

Comment: @whuber so by the rank being $k$, does that mean there are $p - k$ linearly dependent columns, and this represents the data "lost" by the reconstruction of PCA?

Comment: When the rank is $k,$ there exist $k$ linearly independent columns, but any set of $l\gt k$ columns will not be linearly independent.