# PCA to reconstruct Binary Data

Tags: pca, binary-data, svd

I'm working with binary 3D matrices. I calculate their PCA (or REOF or SVD) and as a test I would like to reconstruct these matrices from the PCA results. However I realized that because I only keep the first 10 modes of my PCA, the reconstruction ends up giving me floats between 0 and 1 rather than binary numbers.

Can a PCA reconstruction ([see this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/229092/how-to-reverse-pca-and-reconstruct-original-variables-from-several-principal-com)) with only the first principal components return binary numbers ? (binary in -> binary out)

Comment: Welcome to CV.  Could you please elaborate on what you mean by "fit"?  What is your objective?

Comment: Sorry, I will modify the main text. By "fit" I mean that I am expecting a PCA reconstruction to give me back the same type of input I gave in, in that case, binary numbers. However I end up with decimals and not binary. So I was wondering if a PCA reconstruction could work for a binary dataset.

Comment: What, exactly, would you mean by a "PCA reconstruction"?  When you don't use all the PCs, all you get is an *approximation* to the original data in a least squares sense.  When you use all the PCs you will indeed recover the original data (up to some accumulated floating point precision which, except in cases with extremely large dimensions, you can safely just round away).

Comment: You're right maybe I should use the term *approximation*. I only use the first PCs because they explain more than 95% or so of the variance.
I guess that explains that I am not able to recover 0s and 1s if I don't use all the PCs ?

Comment: For example: I use the 5 first PCs that explain 95% of the data's variance. Wouldn't a rounding of the output give the original dataset ? (everything below 0.5 would become 0, everything above 0.5 would become 1).

Or is 5% of unrepresented variance enough to swing the value of some cells ? (for example, 0.85 would become 1 with 5 PCs, but if I reconstruct the data using all the PCs  could it actually be a 0 ?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reconstructed dataset using a subset of principal components is an *orthogonal projection:* a mathematical generalization of the process of rendering a 3D scene as an image.

[image]

This famous [Escher print](https://www.insidehook.com/article/home-goods/exploring-the-impossible-with-artist-m-c-escher) projects a regular array of shapes into fewer dimensions.  *The locations of the shapes in the paper is no longer regular* (it is not a lattice).

Binary data in $n$ dimensions, whose values are limited to $0$ and $1,$ are necessarily located on the integer lattice (of vectors with integral coordinates).  But when projected, even into a space of just one dimension less (as in the Escher print), they will not necessarily appear lattice-like.  Here, for instance, is the projection of 16 binary vectors in $32$ dimensions onto the space spanned by their first two principal components:

[image]

(There is some overlap in the projections, evidenced by the stronger coloration in the overlapping points, yielding only 8 distinct points.)

**It therefore is unrealistic to hope either that such a "partial reconstruction" will have all binary coordinates (which would cause all the points to fall on the integer lattice) or even that rounded versions would correctly reproduce the original data.**

To demonstrate this, here are the original dataset, its reconstruction based on the top five principal components, and the rounded version of that reconstruction.  All are plotted as images in which each column represents a vector.

[image]

(This PCA centered all the columns but did not rescale them.)  This reconstruction accounts for 87% of the variance.  *All* the variance is accounted for by the top seven PCs, indicating this reconstruction is a projection from a space that is inherently of *seven* dimensions into a space of five dimensions.

You can see that many of the reconstructed coordinates are close to $0$ (lightest color) or $1$ (darkest color), but not all are.  At the right, you will notice the rounded reconstruction looks substantially like the original, *but not quite.*  About 1.2% of the coordinates flipped from $0$ to $1$ and another 2.0% of them flipped from $1$ to $0.$

---

Here, to show the details of the calculations, is the `R` code used to generate this example.

```R
#
# Generate binary data.
#
set.seed(17)
p <- 16   # Number of observations
n <- 32   # Dimension of the vectors (cannot be less than `p`)
kmax <- 3 # Roughly, determines the rank of the matrix
A <- matrix(sample(0:1, p * kmax, replace = TRUE), ncol = p)
X <- (matrix(sample(0:1, n * kmax, replace = TRUE), n) %*% A) %% 2
#
# Perform PCA.
#
obj <- princomp(X)
screeplot(obj)      # Charts contributions from the highest PCs
with(obj, signif(cumsum(sdev^2)[1:10] / sum(sdev^2), 3)) # Their contributions
#
# Reconstruct the data from a specified number of PCs.
#
k <- 5 # PCs used for reconstruction
X. <- with(obj, 
           t(zapsmall(loadings[, 1:k, drop = FALSE] %*% t(scores)[1:k, , drop = FALSE] 
                      + center)))
#
# Display `X.`, `X`, and its rounded version as images.
#
par(mfrow = c(1,3))
i <- list(Reconstructed = X., Original = X, Rounded = round(X.))
for (s in names(i)) {
  image(i[[s]], bty = "n", xaxt = "n", yaxt = "n", main = s)
}
par(mfrow = c(1,1))
#
# Evaluate the differences between the original data and the rounded reconstruction.
#
table(X - round(X.)) / length(X)
with(obj, plot(loadings[, 1:2], pch = 21, bg = hsv(0.02, 1, 1, 0.3), 
               xlab = expression(PC[1]), ylab = expression(PC[2])))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this great example ! 
I will have to think of a way to maximize the variance reconstructed without taking too many Principal components, but I will also take a look at how many pixels flip when rounded. If it is about 1% it should be good enough for my case study. 

Thank you for the code as well, it is very instructive !

Answer (score 2):

As you mention, you can always round the output of your floating point PCA/SVD to 0/1, and that may work well enough for your purpose. But, there are other options which are tuned to the binary case and may be able to do more with fewer components (if your data has rank higher than the rank you truncate the principal subspace to).

First, since this is stats overflow, there are probabilistic options. Standard principal components analysis is derived under the assumption that the data has a multivariate normal distribution. In other words, the answer to "which low-dimensional subspace contains the most variance?" has a nice answer in the Gaussian case. Still, for non-Gaussian data (like binary data, typically modeled with the Bernoulli distribution), similar questions can be asked and answered, and these may be more appropriate for your context. For instance, you could consider looking into logistic PCA -- its relation to PCA is something like the relationship between logistic regression and the usual (Gaussian) linear regression. A. Landgraf's [R package of this name](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/logisticPCA/vignettes/logisticPCA.html) may be of interest, and that website points to some nice related literature. As in logistic regression, there are lots of related models which could be of interest. For instance, although [Poisson NMF](https://proceedings.neurips.cc/paper_files/paper/2000/hash/f9d1152547c0bde01830b7e8bd60024c-Abstract.html) models nonnegative integer data, it is also sometimes used on binary count data (although its reconstructions may not be binary).

And second, there is lots of literature about low-rank Boolean matrix factorizations -- [this webpage](https://people.mpi-inf.mpg.de/%7Epmiettin/bmf_tutorial/material.html) has many references and a tutorial. Googling this term and your programming language of choice should turn up useful implementations of standard algorithms. For instance, the Nimfa package in Python includes some.

Comment: Thank you for your answer !! I really appreciate the links, and for the Logistic PCA suggestion. I did not know about this technique, it might be more adapted to my study case.