# PCA using prcomp and princomp in R

Tags: r, pca, svd, eigenvalues

I have been trying to do Principal Component Analysis (PCA) via R.

 The data set is available at https://www.dropbox.com/s/s3jstl8pu1e1xcp/Cars.csv?dl=0 
 I tried to do PCA via 2 different methods -

- prcomp
- princomp

I have used correlation matrix as all the variables are on different scales.
Whilst, I can understand a slight difference, there appears to be a major difference between the two. I have illustrated the same below -

> car <- read.csv("D:/Cars.csv")
>       
>  car <- car[,c(2:7)]
>       
>  pc <- princomp(car, score=TRUE, cor=TRUE)
>       
>  pca <- prcomp(car, score=TRUE, cor=TRUE)
>       
>  summary(pca); summary(pc)

The result of the above is -

[image: result]

We can see the summary of the prcomp method above and the princomp method below. 
As visible, both are **extremely** different : in the sdev as well as the proportion of variance.

Further, their respective components are also vastly different, as is visible below -

[image: loading]

prcomp is above and princomp is below in the pic, once again.

Can somebody please explain as to why there is such a huge difference between the two ? Also, are these two methods the correct ones to perform PCA or should I go ahead with a different method (e.g. PCA() )

 Thanks in advance :)

Comment: To use the correlation matrix with `prcomp`, you need `scale=TRUE` (not `score=TRUE`).

Comment: Can this be a related question? http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/20101/3277

Comment: Thanks a lot Hong Ooi! (y)
It worked perfectly using > scale=TRUE Seems a stupid question, but can you please help tell what is the purpose of score in the princomp function ?