# Why are the singular values of a standardized data matrix not equal to the eigenvalues of its correlation matrix?

Tags: r, correlation, pca, svd

Conceptually, aren't the eigenvalues of a correlation matrix and the singular values of the associated scaled data matrix supposed to be the same? The below illustration is saying that it isn't so. Please point out what I am missing.

```
> M
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    6   11
[2,]    2    7   12
[3,]    3    8   21
[4,]    4    9   14
[5,]    5   10   34
> M.scale = scale(M)
> M.cor.eigen = eigen(cor(M))
> M.prcomp = prcomp(M.scale)
> M.svd = svd(M.scale)
> M.cor.eigen$values
    [1] 2.729542e+00 2.704577e-01 1.198779e-16
    > M.prcomp$sdev ^ 2
[1] 2.729542e+00 2.704577e-01 5.960165e-34
> M.svd$d
[1] 3.304265e+00 1.040111e+00 1.953076e-16
```

Comment: Singular values of `M` are sq. root of eigenvalues of `M'M`. Correlation matrix for the columns of `M` [is](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/22520/3277) `Z'Z/(n-1)` where `Z` is `M` after standardizing its columns. Therefore, to see the equivalence you have to divide your last singular values, after squaring them, by `5-1`. This is what Marc is saying in his answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe this has to do with the fact that for both `cor()` and `prcomp` "variances are computed with the usual divisor N-1" (also see comments of [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/9500/why-do-the-r-functions-pca-and-prcomp-give-different-eigenvalues?rq=1)). If you do an `svd()` on the correlation matrix, the results are the same:

```
svd(cor(M))$d
#[1] 2.729542e+00 2.704577e-01 1.317513e-16
```

Or, as somone commented earlier, dividing the squared singular values by (N-1) will also work:

```
M.svd$d^2 / (nrow(M)-1)
#[1] 2.729542e+00 2.704577e-01 9.536263e-33
```

A more direct comparison to SVD would be to use `princomp()`, which "uses divisor N for the covariance matrix":

```
M <- matrix(rnorm(200, mean=3, sd=5), 20, 10)
M.scale = scale(M)
x1 <- princomp(M.scale)$sdev^2 * nrow(M)
x2 <- svd(M.scale)$d^2
plot(x1, x2)
abline(0,1)
```

[image]