# Princomp() outputs seemingly wrong PCA scores with cor=TRUE input argument

Tags: r, pca

Given a 2D data frame `d`  that is centered and scaled:

```
d = data.frame(x = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10), y = c(3,5,6,8,3,9,3,5,7,15))
d = as.data.frame(scale(d,center=TRUE, scale = TRUE))
```

the correlation matrix and the covariance matrix are the same:

```
all.equal(cov(d),cor(d)) # this equals TRUE, meaning cov(d) and cor(d) are equal
```

Now if you use `princomp` to do PCA and compare the loadings/eigenvectors produced when you specify to use the covariance matrix (`cor=FALSE`) vs. the correlation matrix (`cor=TRUE`) you get the same loadings as expected:

```
princomp(d, cor = TRUE)$loading
princomp(d, cor = FALSE)$loading
```

but the scores that are produced are not the same:

```
princomp(d, cor = TRUE)$scores
princomp(d, cor = FALSE)$scores

head(princomp(d, cor = TRUE)$scores,3)
#         Comp.1     Comp.2
# [1,] 1.7950077 -0.4206391
# [2,] 1.1445987 -0.5786822
# [3,] 0.6963027 -0.5346122

head(princomp(d, cor = FALSE)$scores,3)
#         Comp.1     Comp.2
# [1,] 1.7028938 -0.3990533
# [2,] 1.0858616 -0.5489861
# [3,] 0.6605707 -0.5071777
```

**Why?**

PCA scores are just the original data, `d`, multiplied by the eigenvectors (i.e. loadings). The `d` is the same in both calls to `princomp` and the matrix being decomposed is the same since `cov(d)=cor(d)` so why the difference in scores?

Calculated manually the original data times the eigenvectors matches the output when `cor=FALSE`:

```
head(as.matrix(d) %*% as.matrix(princomp(d)$loading),3)
```

---

#### Trying to understand the source code

To see what is happening look at the the code for the `princomp()` function by typing

```
getAnywhere("princomp.default")
```

I reconstructed the source code to see what is happening when `cor=TRUE` vs. when `cor=FALSE`.  Here is the source code moved around so you can match the output `cor=TRUE` vs. `cor=FALSE`:

```
z = as.matrix(d)
sd_of_original_data = apply(d,2,sd)  # this is 1 because the data was scaled
covmat <- cov.wt(z)
n.obs <- covmat$n.obs
cv <- covmat$cov * (1 - 1/n.obs)
cen <- covmat$center

# if cor = TRUE code does this: i.e CORRELATION MATRIX code
sds <- sqrt(diag(cv))
sds   # this is .9486833 for both columns
cv_cor <- cv/(sds %o% sds)
cv_cor
edc_cor <- eigen(cv_cor, symmetric = TRUE)
ev_cor <- edc$values
sc_cor = sds
scr_cor = scale(z, center = cen, scale = sc_cor) %*% edc_cor$vectors
# reconstructed scores using source code match princomp output
scr_cor
princomp(d, center = FALSE, scale = FALSE, cor= TRUE)$scores

# if cor = FALSE code does this: i.e COVARAINCE MATRIX code
edc <- eigen(cv, symmetric = TRUE)
ev <- edc$values
sdev <- sqrt(ev)
sc = rep(1, ncol(cv)) #, colnames(cv)
scr = scale(z, center=cen, scale=sc) %*% edc$vectors
# reconstructed scores using source code match princomp output
scr
princomp(d, center=FALSE, scale=FALSE, cor=FALSE)$scores
```

First note that the source code has this division

```
 covmat$cov * (1 - 1/n.obs)
```

and note  `covmat$cov` has ones on the diagonal, i.e. `sd(covmat$cov) = 1`, but once you multiply by* `(1 - 1/n.obs) then sd(covmat$cov) != 1`. This is the issue. Details below.

1. When `cor=TRUE` the `cv` (covariance matrix) is divided by the outer product of the matrix that is the cv/(sds %o% sds). Note `sds` is the `sqrt(diag(cv))` and `sds` are .94 for both columns of data. The `sd_of_original_data` has sds of 1 for both columns because the original data was standardized. **When `cor=FALSE` this division does not take place.**

   Notice when the data is centered and scaled `diag(cv)` will not be 1s because of the original choice to do this:  `cv <- covmat$cov * (1 - 1/n.obs)`. Above when cor= TRUE, `sds= diag(cv)` returns non-one values whereas when `cor=FALSE` sds equals a vector of 1s.  This "sds" vector which is a function of `cv <- covmat$cov * (1 - 1/n.obs)` is the reason the scores are different because below the scores are scaled by sds.
2. When `cor=TRUE` the scores are created from scaling the original data matrix, `z`,  by `sc_cor` which are the `sds`. Then multiplying by the eigenvectors, `edc_cor` which remember were computed using `cv_cor` which had the division in step 1.

   ```
   sc_cor =sds
   scr_cor = scale(z, center=cen, scale=sc_cor) %*% edc_cor$vectors
   ```

   vs. when cor = FALSE the scores are created by scaling the original data matrix by 1 and multiplying by the eigenvectors, edc of cv. This seems to be the textbook PCA score calculation.

   ```
   sc = rep(1, ncol(cv)) #, colnames(cv)
   scr = scale(z, center = cen, scale = sc) %*% edc$vectors
   ```

   So initially I thought if `cor(d) = cov(d)` the PCA loadings and scores would be the same. Obviously the covariance matrix you think princomp is using is sometimes not actually used. Instead it is modified.

   It seems to avoid all of this confusion you can always pass the covariance matrix you want to use in the "covmat" parameter to princomp. Then you will have control over the covariance matrix used in the PCA. If you don't want the cv scaled by (1 - 1/n.obs) you can just pass the proper cv in "covmat".

   Notice there are different ways to scale the covariance matrix. [Here](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/cov.wt.html) is help of the `cov.wt()` used in the source code.

   By default, method = "unbiased", The covariance matrix is divided by one minus the sum of squares of the weights, so if the weights are the default (1/n) the conventional unbiased estimate of the covariance matrix with divisor (n - 1) is obtained. This differs from the behaviour in S-PLUS which corresponds to method = "ML" and does not divide.

Also a question. The source code has scaling of the covariance matrix for weights.

```
 cv <- covmat$cov * (1 - 1/n.obs)
```

but I am confused if you look at getAnywhere("cov.wt") it is already scaling.

```
Here is the data and the result from cov.wt() and the source code used to calculated cov.wt.   See getAnywhere("cov.wt")

d = data.frame(x = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10), y=c(3,5,6,8,3,9,3,5,7,15))
d = as.data.frame(scale(d,center=TRUE, scale=TRUE))
cov.wt(d)$cov
##### here is what cov.wt is doing see getAnywhere("cov.wt")
wt = rep(.1,10)
center = colSums(wt * d)
x <- sqrt(wt) * sweep(d, 2, center, check.margin=FALSE)
crossprod(as.matrix(x))/(1 - sum( wt^2 ))  # this is cov.wt(d)$cov
```

See the denominator in the last line  (1 -  sum( wt^2 )) ... so why the need to the scale this result again by it is already scaling for the weights so by (1 - 1/n.obs)?

See the "Weighted Samples" section here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sample_mean_and_covariance

> "If all weights are the same .... the weighted mean and covariance reduce to the sample mean and covariance above."

Essentially (1 - sum( wt^2 ))  in the source code of cov.wt() is the same as the (1 - 1/n.obs) term used to multiple cov.wt() in the source code of princomp() because the weights are the same, 1/n  (sum(wt^2) == 1/n.obs)...so they are scaling twice?

Comment: @amoeba It is *definitely* the $n$ vs. $n-1$.  It's exactly the same issue.  Just compare the two sets of loadings by dividing one by the other and squaring: the ratio is $9/10$.

Comment: @amoeba the source code of cov.wt shows scaling already taking place. it appears be scaling twice?

Comment: @whuber do you see a second unnecessary scaling here?

Comment: @whuber I figured out what is going on (see my answer). You were of course right. When run with `cor=TRUE` argument, the `princomp` function $z$-scores the data but it does so using $1/n$ factor instead of $1/(n-1)$. So it certainly affects the scores ("projections").

Comment: FWIW, I retracted my own close vote because that thread does not contain an answer to this Q after my answer edit has been rolled back by the original answerer.

Comment: Hey @user3022875, consider deleting this last comment of yours: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2691/making-sense-of-principal-component-analysis-eigenvectors-eigenvalues/140579#comment459697_140579 - I think it's obsolete there (and the comment section under that answer is really crowded...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**I do not recommend using `princomp()` because it is a source of constant confusion. Use `prcomp()` instead.**

`Princomp()` computes covariance matrix using the $1/n$ factor, instead of the more standard $1/(n-1)$ factor, which means that the eigenvalues returned by `princomp` and by any other R function such as e.g. `prcomp` or `eigen(cov())` will, very confusingly, differ: [Why do the R functions 'princomp' and 'prcomp' give different eigenvalues?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/9500)

Your issue is very related to that (as correctly identified by @whuber in the comments). When `princomp` is run with `cor=FALSE` input argument (which is the default), it computes eigenvectors of the covariance matrix, centers the data, and projects the data onto the eigenvectors. When run with `cor=TRUE`, the function computes eigenvectors of the correlation matrix, $z$-scores the data *using variances computed with $1/n$ factor*,  and projects the data onto the eigenvectors.

This means that PCA scores produced by the following two lines will be slightly different (because `scale` uses $n-1$):

```
 princomp(scale(data))$scores
 princomp(data, cor=T)$scores
```

**I find this counter-intuitive and confusing.** As @ttnphns points out in the comments, using $n$ is not necessarily worse than using $n-1$. But `princomp`'s choice is inconsistent with almost all other R functions, leading to great confusion.

If you supply already $z$-scored data and specify `cor=TRUE`, the function will $z$-score the data again, according to its own liking, by multiplying each column with $\sqrt{(n-1)/n}$. This is the difference that you observe.

*(See [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20101) about an unrelated algorithmic difference between `princomp` and `prcomp`.)*

---

#### Some comments on the source code

Let us take a look at the code that you provided. The function starts with computing the covariance matrix and then multiplying it with `(1 - 1/n.obs)`. You are over-thinking this; it simply converts $1/(n-1)$ factor into $1/n$ factor, because $1-1/n=(n-1)/n$. So okay, covariance matrix is now scaled to be maximum likelihood (instead of unbiased).

When `cor=FALSE` (which is the default), the scores are computed as

```
 scr =  scale(z, center = cen, scale = sc) %*% edc$vectors
```

which is centered data (non-scaled: `sc` is equal to `1`) multiplied by the eigenvectors.

When `cor=TRUE`, the scores are computed with the same formula, but now the `sc` variable is set to `sqrt(diag(cv))` where `cv` is the ML covariance matrix. As you wrote yourself, in your case `sc=.9486833`, which is $\sqrt{9/10}$. So even though you $z$-scored your data, `princomp` will re-$z$-score it for you because it prefers different denominator. Hence the confusion.

Comment: I'm a bit surprised with this particular answer of yours, amoeba, especially with "Princomp() is better to be avoided" categorical sentence. I'm here _not_ to advocate prcomp or princomp - I use neither of them. But I see Princomp's calculations - as you've described them - as a viable _variant_. In computation of correlations the df (n or n-1) doesn't matter since it [cancels out](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/22520/3277). Hence, the choice of n or n-1 in standardizing the variables to produce component scores is arbitrary. Results differ, but neither of the two is "better" than the other.

Comment: (cont.)  I know programs which computes PCA scores with n-1, or with n, or with both options. And also, I would personally prefer (and advice to other) the eigen-based PCA than svd-based PCA because I see speed is more important in practical data analysis than numerical precision (we've [discussed it](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/87536/3277)). I would, however, agree that Princomp() isn't flexible enough.

Comment: @ttnphns I can see the validity of some of your points though, so I rewrote my answer. Please see if you find it fairer now.

Comment: I'm happy that somebody (you in this instance) could eventually figure out and aid the sufferer. And I really like you answer in its last edit.

Comment: I would just like to point out that I wasn't "guessing": the thread I pointed to as a duplicate made it clear what was going on.

Comment: @whuber :-) Happy to replace "guessed" with "identified".

Comment: @amoeba when I am referring to double scaling I am referring to this line of code in princomp:  cv <- covmat$cov * (1 - 1/n.obs).  cov.wt() uses "unbiased" as it's default "method" parameter and in the cov.wt() source code you can see cov is set to crossprod(x)/(1 - sum(wt^2))  so the first line I referenced is really cv<-  crossprod(x)/(1 - sum(wt^2)) * (1 - 1/n.obs).

Comment: There are 2 scalings of the crossprod matrix there. First by 1/(1 - sum(wt^2))  and second by  (1 - 1/n.obs) and those scalings are the same.  If you look at the cov.wt() code and the details description,  if method = "ML" is passed then the scaling of 1/(1 - sum(wt^2))  does not occur. I think princomp authors probably wanted the behavior of cov.wt(0 when method = "ML" because they are applyng their own (redundant)   (1 - 1/n.obs) scaling.  Inside princomp I think the cov.wt() call should be cov.wt(method ="ML") then crossprod(x) will be returned with a single scaling of *  (1 - 1/n.obs)

Comment: @user3022875 Yes, princomp authors want to get the ML cov matrix. Running cov.wt with method=ML would make sense, but princomp's authors decided to run cov.wt with default "unbiased" method, and then manually convert unbiased estimate into ML estimate (why? no idea). The line of code that you refer to does exactly that. The scaling inside cov.wt is $1/(1-1/n) = n/(n-1)$, so it takes ML estimate and converts it unto unbiased. And then princomp multiplies it by $(1-1/n)=(n-1)/n$ so it takes unbiased estimate and converts it into ML. It's stupid but that's what is happening. Do you agree?

Comment: Yes I see the two scalings cancel each other out.  In  the details of princomp here: http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/princomp.html -> "Note that the default calculation uses divisor N for the covariance matrix."  If the two scalings cancel each other out then there is no N for the divisor of the covariance matrix correct?

Comment: @user3022875 No. Incorrect. If you look again in the cov.wt source code, you will see that `x` is multiplied by `sqrt(wt)` just before calling `crossprod(x)` which means that x is scaled by $1/\sqrt{n}$ so that `crossprod` yields covariance matrix with $1/n$ factor. This is ML estimate. This is what `princomp` will be using in the end. Does it make sense?

Comment: Yes it does apologies for not seeing he 1/sqrt(n) out front. Thank you.

Comment: @user3022875 So do you think the issue is completely clarified or is there still something unclear here?

Comment: I'd say it is clarified. princomp takes unbiased estimates and converts to ML.The scaling seen in princomp is canceling out the default "unbiased" scaling seen in  cov.wt().